# Обязательно ли при переопределении equals переопределять и hashCode?

Tags: java

Я неоднократно слышал о том, что рекомендуют при переопределении метода `equals` переопределять и `hashCode`. Но так рекомендуют, что вроде и не откажешь.

Есть ли какое-то соглашение о том, что если я переопределяю `equals`, то и `hashCode` тоже **обязан** переопределять, а в противном случае код не будет считаться корректным? Или это просто рекомендация?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Вы переопределите `equals(...)`, но не переопределите `hashCode()`, то в некоторых случаях Ваша программа будет вести себя некорректно.

В частности это проявляется для объектов, которые являются ключами в `HashMap`.

Если объекты равны, то и их хэш-коды должны быть равны.

Answer (score 2):

Для поддержания общего договора - [равные объекты должны иметь одинаковый хеш-код](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))